# How to run cucumber test with a particular data using outline?

Tags: cucumber

```
Given "step" like "description"                              
  Example:                                     
  | step | description |                
  |  1   | first       |                 
  |  2   | second      |           
  |  1   | third       |            
  |  2   | fourth      |
```

if i want to run it'll take  as 1,2,1,2.

But i need my test should run with  as 1. no need to get the data from  2.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tag the examples and run them partially as follows:

```
Given "step" like "description"  

    @ones                            
  Examples:                                     
  | step | description |                
  |  1   | first       |                 
  |  1   | third       |            

    @twos                            
  Examples:                                     
  | step | description |                
  |  2   | second      |           
  |  2   | fourth      |
```

To run only the data with 1s:

```
$cucumber --tags @ones
```

Or exclude data with 2s:

```
$cucumber --tags ~@twos
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply prakash. Now i'm able to run with a particular data.